# How do I check for a 32-bit z-buffer using Managed Direct3D?

Tags: .net, directx, c++-cli, direct3d, managed-directx

I understand that a call to `Manager::CheckDepthStencilMatch` should get me an answer, but so far I have not been able to gather the pieces required to make this call effectively.

In particular, I need to obtain values for the `adapterFormat` and `renderTargetFormat` arguments. I am not specifying any particular format while creating the device so I need a way to get the default/current 'Format' values.

Comment: Be warned your are unlikely to FIND that 32-bit depth buffer.  Unless of course you mean D32F_LOCKABLE.  Or D24X8/D24S8?  Not seen a card support D32 since the Savage 3D ...

Comment: @Goz, DepthFormat::D32 works fine on my machine. The card is a "VIA/S3G DeltaChrome IGP". However, I am using Managed Direct3D here... Could that be the reason it works?

Comment: Typical.  Its an "S3" card and the Savage3D was an S3 card ;)  Don't expect it to work on nVidia or ATI cards ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--

```
D3D::DepthFormat GetDepthFormat(){
    D3D::AdapterInformation ^adapter = D3D::Manager::Adapters->Default;
    D3D::DepthFormat depthFormat = D3D::DepthFormat::D32;
    if(!D3D::Manager::CheckDepthStencilMatch(0,
        D3D::DeviceType::Hardware, adapter->CurrentDisplayMode.Format,
        adapter->CurrentDisplayMode.Format, depthFormat)){

        depthFormat = D3D::DepthFormat::D16;
        if(!D3D::Manager::CheckDepthStencilMatch(0,
            D3D::DeviceType::Hardware, adapter->CurrentDisplayMode.Format,
            adapter->CurrentDisplayMode.Format, depthFormat)){

            throw gcnew Exception(L"Your hardware needs to be upgraded.");
        }
    }

    return depthFormat;
}
```